# Why cudaStreamCreate gets segmentation fault

Tags: cuda, segmentation-fault

There are four Tesla C2075 in my server, so I just tested the sample simpleMultiGPU that came with the SDK. Unexpectedly I got a segmentation fault. With cuda-gdb I found this fault occurred when cudaStreamCreate is called the second time. Here is the deviceQuery output:

```
$ deviceQuery

CUDA Driver = CUDART,

CUDA Driver Version = 4.2, 

CUDA Runtime Version = 4.2, 

NumDevs = 4, 

Device = Tesla C2075,

Device = Tesla C2075
```

The driver version is ok, so why the second cudaStreamCreate doesn't work. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with running nvidia-healthmon which can be downloaded from https://developer.nvidia.com/tesla-deployment-kit (it's a part of TDK).

Also output of `nvidia-bug-report.sh` is always very helpful. Also log from `nvidia-healthmon` (`--log-file` flag) might give us some clue.

Are there any other applications that are failing? It'd be good to rule out other possibilities by running other apps from the SDK like `vectorAdd` or `matrixMul`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, MonteCarloMultiGPU also gives segmentation fault, but this time I found it occurred when cudaMallocHost was called. I will try nvidia-healthmon for more clue!